# The object's size changes with rotating it around an axis in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, rotation, transformation

I have a triangle :

```
static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 
1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 
0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
```

I translated my triangle in z-axis. Then I tried it rotate around x and y-axis:

```
mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(mat4(1.0f), rotation, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
mat4 translationMatrix = glm::translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(position.x, position.y, -2.3f));

mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(90.0f, WindowWidth/WindowHeight, 1.0f, 1000.0f);
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core


layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;
uniform mat4 rotationMatrix;
uniform mat4 translationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix*rotationMatrix*translationMatrix* vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1.0f);

}
```

Because I can't add images I have to add the images' links:

Without transformation:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1eompnmjauvll9x/3.png

Rotation around x-axis:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9bpqb6nfudruuhx/ilk.png

Rotation around y-axis:
www.dropbox.com/s/xxk9ofxfp4zk8ta/2.png

This seems anormal to me. Why does it happen?

Comment: Are you sure that this actually is a bug? it seems like this might just be a result of your projection matrix. Try rotating a 1 unit cube around its own axis at 3 units away and see if it gets distorted.

Comment: This thread is dead but, here are some things to watch out for.
Always make sure that you're doing transformations for position, rotation and scale separately. As in create an individual matrix for each one and then multiply afterward rather than doing all at once, and make sure that when you're rotating your object you are not using a quaternion if so you should rotate it with the rotate function and not change the XYZ values as if you are using Euler angles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks normal to me.

As you're not using a view matrix, the result of your transform (and thus, the vertex coordinates that you'll see on screen, after projection) will show a triangle that heavily distorts (getting bigger in the Y direction) as it rotates towards you, and the other way around, getting smaller when it rotates away from you.

If you want to make sure your transform is correct, add a view matrix :

```
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(5.0), glm::vec3(0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
```

You can send it as a uniform to your shader and make it look like this :

```
gl_Position = projectionMatrix*viewMatrix*rotationMatrix*translationMatrix* vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace,1.0f);
```

If you can still see the distortion effect, then the problem actually exists, but from your code, my guess is that it's already all working well :)